# Why am I getting segmentation fault 11? [C]

Tags: c, fault

I'm new to C and trying to figure out why I'm getting a segmentation fault in the following code. All I'm trying to do here is check that my first argument contains a .txt, and the program will print whether or not I do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {


    char filename = argv[1];
    char *txt_filename = filename;
    char *check_txt = ".txt";

    char *txtvalid = strstr(txt_filename, check_txt); 

    if (txtvalid)   {   

        printf("You have entered a correct text file!");

    }
    else    {

        printf("You have entered an incorrect text file!");
    }   


}
```

When I run this code, I get a segmentation fault 11. I'm not sure what that means. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `char filename = argv[1];` --> `char *filename = argv[1];`

Comment: You should compile with warnings on. e.g. if you are using `gcc`, use `gcc -Wall source.c`. (I would also add `-Werror` probably) It will show warnings with `char` assigned to `char*` & vice versa.

Comment: Are you passing command line arguments. And I think you need to allocate memory for txtvalid

Comment: These comments could be answers. (The type of `filename` was wrong, and even after that is corrected, you can still get a segfault after calling with no commandline arguments.) Usually comments are for clarifications, but I guess there's nothing wrong with answering in a comment. I need to read MetaStackOverflow more.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix them all.  Don't post here until it compiles cleanly with no errors or warnings (or else post the warning if you aren't sure how to eliminate it).

Comment: Now _that_ was a good comment :)

Comment: ok thanks guys all these responses help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test `argc` before accessing `argv`

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {

    // Check for argument
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Missing argument\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];     // Notice this change, i.e. *filename
    char *txt_filename = filename;
    char *check_txt = ".txt";

    char *txtvalid = strstr(txt_filename, check_txt); 

    if (txtvalid)   {   

        printf("You have entered a correct text file!");

    }
    else    {

        printf("You have entered an incorrect text file!");
    }   


}
```

Comment: ill give this a try

Comment: i can confirm this has worked for me, yeah i didnt realise i had to assign filename as a pointer. thanks for the help!